# Android how to restart Timer Handler?

Tags: android, button, timer, handler, restart

I want to know how to restart a Timer after on Button click after timer has been stopped.
What I want is:

1. first button click: timer start
2. second click: timer stop
3. third click: timer restart

The first two are working but not the restart.

```
private Button startButton;

private TextView timerValue;

private long startTime = 0L;

private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;

private int checkState = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pyramide);

    timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pyramideTime);

    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pyramideButton);

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // start
            if (checkState == 0) {
                startButton.setText("Fertig");
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
                checkState = 1;
            }
            // pause
            else if (checkState == 1) {
                startButton.setText("Neu starten");
                timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
                checkState = 2;
            }
            // restart
            else if (checkState == 2) {
                timerValue.setText("0");
                timeInMilliseconds = 0L;

                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
                checkState = 0;
                startButton.setText("Fertig");
            }
        }
    });

}

private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
        timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs)
                + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this using a counter :

```
 startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        int counter = 0;
    public void onClick(View view) {
                                        counter++;
                                    if (counter == 1) {
            startButton.setText("Fertig");
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
                                    else if (counter == 2) {
            startButton.setText("Neu starten");
            timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
            customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
                                    }
                                    else if (counter ==3) {
            timerValue.setText("0");
            timeInMilliseconds = 0L;

            customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
            startButton.setText("Fertig");
            counter = 0;
}
}
});
```